# How to access a method in a specific child component that is used twice or more in Angular?

Tags: angular

**Here is what I am building:**

A switch widget that is a checkbox and a button. When the checkbox is checked the button is clickable. When the checkbox is unchecked the button is disabled. The checkbox itself can be set to disabled.

**What I have built so far:**

switch.ts which contains a switch class with 3 properties: name, disabled and state.

```
export class Switch {
    state: boolean;
    disabled: boolean;
    name: string;
    constructor(name?: string,
                state?: false,
                disabled?: false) {}
}
```

switch.Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Switch } from './switch';

@Component({
    selector: 'st-switch',
    templateUrl: './switch.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./switch.component.scss']
})
export class SwitchComponent {
    switch = new Switch();

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.switch.name = 'switch name';
        this.switch.state = false;
        this.switch.disabled = false;
    }

  toggle() {
    if(this.switch.state === false) {
      this.switch.state = true;
    } else {
      this.switch.state = false;
    }
  }

  setOn() {
    this.switch.state = true;
  }

  setOff() {
    this.switch.state = false;
  }

  setDisabled() {
    this.switch.disabled = true;
  }

  setEnabled() {
    this.switch.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

switch.component.html

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" (click)="toggle()" [disabled]="switch.disabled">
    <span class="slider"></span>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-confirm" [disabled]="!switch.state">{{switch.name}}</button>
</label>
```

**What I'm having a problem with**

I need to be able to set the switch state, if it is disabled or not and name from another component (programmatically) which uses the switch and this other component can have more than one switch.

**What I have tried**

https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-viewchild-example

Here's the other component (events-form) which uses switch.component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, HostListener, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {EventPlannerService} from '../../services/event-planner.service';
import {StEvent} from '../../model/st-event';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {EventsService} from 'app/services/events.service';
import {Notification} from '../notifications/notification';
import {NotificationType} from '../notifications/notification-type';
import {NotificationsService} from '../../services/notifications.service';
import {AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, ValidatorFn, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {SlowFadingAnimation} from '../../app.animations';
import { ComponentCanDeactivate } from '../../guards/pending-changes.guard';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { SwitchComponent } from '../switch/switch.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'st-event-form',
  templateUrl: './event-form.component.html',
  animations: [
    SlowFadingAnimation
  ],
  styleUrls: ['./event-form.component.scss'],
  providers: [EventPlannerService]
})
export class EventFormComponent implements OnInit, ComponentCanDeactivate {
  @ViewChild(SwitchComponent)
  private switchComponent: SwitchComponent;
  setOn() {
     this.switchComponent.setOn();
  }
  setOff() {
     this.switchComponent.setOff();
  }
  setDisabled() {
     this.switchComponent.setDisabled();
  }
  setEnabled() {
    this.switchComponent.setEnabled();
  }
...
```

And here's the other component (events-form) html, I include the 2 switch instances like so:

```
...
      <div class="form-group">
        <st-switch></st-switch>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <st-switch></st-switch>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="eventDetailsForm.pristine" class="btn btn-success pull-right">SAVE</button>
    </form>
```

**What I would like to be able to do**

How do I access a method called setOn(), setOff or any other method that is part of switch.component from events-form.component when there is more than one switch in an events-form? (programmatically)

[component-nesting-layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASQSF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ViewChild works great when you have one unique child that you can watch. If I were you I'd use @Output and eventEmitters to easily distinguish between the switches.

First of all, add the event emitter to the switch component:

```
export class SwitchComponent {
    switch = new Switch();
    @Input() name = defaultName; // can be changed from parent
    @Output() change = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() { }

    toggle() {
        this.switch.state = !this.switch.state; // here's a shorthand for toggling boolean values
        this.change.emit(this.switch.state);
    }
```

Then in your parent template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <st-switch [name]="switch1name" (change)=onChange('first')></st-switch>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <st-switch [name]="switch2name" (change)=onChange('second')></st-switch>
</div>
```

Then in the parent model:

```
onChange(switch) {
    if (switch === 'first') { 
        this.switch1name = 'newSwitchName'; // you can set any properties like this
    }
    else if (switch === 'second') { // do stuff for the second switch }
}
```

You can emit different events for different actions but you get the idea hopefully. This doesn't require @ViewChild at all. Also, you might want to check out this article: https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2

I hope this helps!

Comment: I get what you've made here and have researched the topic, but I still don't see how I can call another components method or set a variable value.

onChange(x) {
    if(x === 1) {
        how to set switch.name here?
    }
}

Comment: Please, see the updated answer, I added the functionality for controlling the switch properties from parent.

Comment: After posting my comment I found and figured out the same solution as your updated answer. Thanks for helping me get there Boris. :)

Comment: Great! Happy to help! :)